# Drupal 8: view not appearing on my custom theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

In D8, I have created a custom theme. Then, I created a view and assigned the same into a region. I see the view is not showing anywhere in the theme. To test further, I change the theme to Bartik and the view is showing in the Bartik theme. Can anyone suggest to me why the view is not appearing on my custom theme? Below are the codes for my custom theme:

```
//test.info.yml


name: Test
description: A custom theme
type: theme
core: 8.x

regions:
    navigation: Navigation
    header: Header
    quote1: Quote1
    content: Content
    services: Services
    works: Works
    quote2: Quote2
    blog: Blog
    contact: Contact
    footer: Footer

libraries:
    - 'test/global-css'
    - 'test/global-js'
```

below is the `test.libraries.yml` code

```
global-css:
    css:
        theme:
            css/bootstrap-responsive.css: {}
            css/style.css: {}
            color/default.css: {}

global-js:
    js:
        js/jquery.js: {}
        js/jquery.scrollTo.js: {}
        js/jquery.nav.js: {}
        js/jquery.localScroll.js: {}
        js/bootstrap.js: {}
        js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js: {}
        js/isotope.js: {}
        js/jquery.flexslider.js: {}
        js/inview.js: {}
        js/animate.js: {}
        js/custom.js: {}

    dependencies:
        - core/jquery
```

Below is the code of `page.html.twig`:

```
{{ page.content }}
```

Note: I'm using Drupal version 8.7.3

Comment: How do you assign your view to a region ? To which one ?

Comment: Hi @EricLavault I have made this thing working, From the config the block, I have check the content type visibility of a content type Article. That's why the view was not showing into the region.

Answer (score 1):

You should be placing your view in the content region.

You can make sure of this by placing any other content on that specific region and seeing if it works.  If it works, then see settings of your view.

Otherwise, see if your region is placed properly in your theme.

This article may help you.
[Adding Regions to a Theme](https://drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-regions-to-a-theme)

Comment: I assigned the view into some other regions but no luck. However, the views is showing on the Content region of Bartik theme as said above.

Answer (score 0):

Check the region Wich you assign the view block .and also check that the region printed on twig file.